# Solve equation $(x+1)^{2010}+(x+2)^{2010}=2^{-2009}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve equation $$(x+1)^{2010}+(x+2)^{2010}=2^{-2009}$$

Comment: What did you try? And is $x$ a real?

Comment: give me 1 idea.

Comment: Well clearly $x=-\frac{3}{2}$ is a solution.

Comment: equation $\forall x$

Comment: $x=-\frac{3}{2}$ seem wrong

Comment: @WordShallow ... put a minus & a dollar in your last comment ... SCB's answer looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$2^{-2010}+2^{-2010}=2^{-2009}$$

Differentiate to bound the number of solutions.